# How to prevent overlapping in view?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a view like this.

[image: Actual image]

The problem is, that when the `TextView` size is bigger, it looks like this. [image]

So it overlaps "View all (35)" `TextView`. How to prevent the overlapping? The `ImageView` should be right of TextView, but it has not to overlap "View all (35)". I think you understand. Thank you.

Here's the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semi_bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_extra_large"
        tools:text="Birthday" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/wishlist_public" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semi_bold"
        android:text="View all (35)"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have a few options. Personally I would use ConstraintLayout for this but you could also use LinearLayouts

Comment: I tried almost everything, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your imageView to textView's drawableEnd property, after put it in nested linear layout and give to it a weight.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_extra_large"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Your text here" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </Space>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="View All"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(Please add some of your dimens property that i remove because i didn't had them) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:text="Birthdayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
            android:src="@drawable/wishlist_public"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="View all (35)"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ContraintLayout and use Barrier constraint or Guidline constraint to achiever you desired layout 
**I have fixed using guideline contraint**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.095"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
        tools:text="Birthday" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_adb_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewAll"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="View all (35)"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="333dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.62" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Linearlayout to achieve something like that I use to write this code and I think it can help you achieve this layout design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birthdayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="#111"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View All(35)"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After that, you will get something like that

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS8da.png)